# Firebase security rule with user based access - Permission denied error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My app tries to read documents under the collection 'Sites'. I did a simulated read operation which works fine as is as follows:

```
Profile/'actual profile id'/Sites/'actual site id'
```

This simulated read works probably because I am reading a pre-defined document. I am not sure.

My security rule is as follows:

```
match /Profile/{profile}/Sites/{site} {
 allow read: if isOneOfRoles (get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Profile/$(profile)/Sites/$(site)),['FULL', 'OWNER', 'VIEW']);
}

function getRole(rsc) {return rsc.data.SHARED_WITH[request.auth.token.email];}

function isOneOfRoles(rsc, array) {return isSignedIn() && (getRole(rsc) in array);}
```

And finally my query is as follows:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('Profile/${_firebaseUser.uid}/Sites')
        .where('ARCHIVE',isEqualTo: false)
        .orderBy('DATE',descending: true)
        .getDocuments();
```

My database structure looks like the following:
[image]
I am getting permission denied error in my console. Need help in understanding where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full rule, including the match statement.  The partial rules you're showing now are not sufficient to understand what's going on.  You should also show the relevant data in the database that would be used to make a decision about whether or not to allow access.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is rejecting your query because Firebase [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  You can't use a rule to limit the set of documents that would match the query.

Right now, your query demands to know **all** documents where ARCHIVE = true, but your rule does not allow the query of documents that are dependent on some other documents that are based on data in the query.  The rules engine will not read and check each any every one of those other documents - this is does not scale at all.

You will have to find another way of structuring your data, perhaps by putting the permission within each document itself, and using those permissions as part of the query filter.

Comment: Thanks Doug. But to my understanding the permission 'is in each document' itself i.e the email with the role and it is that very document that I am trying to read. Even if I remove the 'where' clause, it does not make a difference.

Comment: That's still because security rules are not filters.  The query is always going to be rejected because the rule can't assert ahead of time whether or not all the documents are always allowed to be fetched.  It will not perform a get() for each document - that doesn't scale, it would exceed the max 10 gets per rule evaluation, and would be extremely costly otherwise.

Comment: Could you help me with an example as to how you might see this working in a better way please

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to query Firestore with the rules as a query filter
however as the answerer told, once one of those entries fails, all the query is rejected (bc of permissions). So, you will have to peform a two step query: 
1) First obtain the documents that are shared with the user, then access those documents one by one. This can be done by adding a nother collection `shared` with the elements to be shared

Comment: 2) In the profile information, you have to add another entry `shared-docs` with an array of elements that are shared with that specific user to completely restructure the DB